# Cassandra old hint files present in hints folder

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

During cassandra decommission I noticed that the node tries to send hints which takes extremely long time and never completes. I checked the hints folder and found hints that are more than 9+ months old. I am not sure why those old hints are still present in the folder so I decided to delete them. After I deleted them I noticed the following entry in the system.log

```
INFO  [HintsDispatcher:1070] 2021-07-08 11:32:01,056  HintsDispatchExecutor.java:141 - Transferring all hints to /10.199.190.233: 7935f1b5-4725-4dc2-ad6d-b883d53d907d
ERROR [HintsDispatcher:1070] 2021-07-08 11:32:01,061  CassandraDaemon.java:207 - Exception in thread Thread[HintsDispatcher:1070,1,RMI Runtime]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /data/cassandra/data/hints/ce6bb0e3-849f-487d-9274-38b8536b89cf-1603947885707-1.hints
```

Where does Cassandra keep metadata for the hints as system.hints folder didn't have any entry?

Cassandra Version is 3.0.12

Comment: How did you remove hints file?

Comment: Manually deleted them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a catalog of hints held in memory on each Cassandra node for tracking.

If you manually delete the contents of the hints directory on a node, the entries in the hints catalog become stale and you run into the `NoSuchFileException` you posted.

The correct way of deleting hints is with the `nodetool truncatehints` command. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @Erick Ramirez is perfectly valid. The downside is that it removes all hints.

If you just want to remove leftover hints (as in the question) which are way past the `max_hint_window_in_ms` (which defaults to 3 hours), or even if you ran into an error because of a corrupted hint, here is a way to remove only selected hints safely inspired by the [datastax documentation](https://support.datastax.com/s/article/ERROR-Failed-to-dispatch-hints-file-s-file-is-corrupted):

1. Turn cassandra off on the given node, make sure there are no leftover java processes
2. Delete the selected hints from the hint filesystem (make sure to delete both the `.hints` and `.crc32` files if they are present)
3. Start cassandra.